# What are the answers for these basic quetions?

Tags: linear-algebra

It has been a while I was away from maths, and I am doing a comeback. 
I would highly appreciated if someone (in detail, and plain 6th grade English) can explain these to me.

1. B : {0, 1}<sup>d</sup> --> {0, 1}<sup>d</sup>
2. A Є {0, 1}<sup>d</sup>
3. uniform distribution
4. vectors (I know they have more than a single characteristics, like direction and weight) but what doe they mean inside cryptography, for example, vectors of sub keys).
5. differential (what does it mean in general? does it mean differences between numbers or so. An example would be appreciated. For example, what does Differential XOR mean)

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello! These questions are quite broad and I would suggest asking them separately: having to write a long answer could discourage some users, who lack time to adequately explain this variety of concepts. Some info on your mathematical background might also be useful to write an answer which is adequate to your knowledge of the field. Following these two tips, your curiosity will probably be satisfied soon. Cheers!

Comment: @bharb: Don't be so tough with tony. Part of our duty is to drive honest inquirers to the right direction. Besides the questions are not that broad.

Comment: @zoli it's okay. Thanks a lot for your support in this community. It is with people like you that new comers are welcomed. Although I have to admit that harsh moderator behavior for new comers, drives them away. Unfortunately.

Comment: I did not mean to be tough at all, maybe my prose did not convey my message. I am very happy that tony is working on cryptography and I encourage him to do so; I just believe the answers could have been more deep than a simple list if the various topics were dealt with separately. Take for example the concept of differential: it is not straight-forward and, due to its importance, it deserves some time to fully appreciate its potential.

Comment: You are right, too. Now we are three. :)

Comment: @bharb did you ban me from asking questions ? Why am I getting the `We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.` error ?

Comment: Maybe you should see the Help Center to learn more?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I did. However, It was my first question here. Banning me from asking other questions is just rude. (given that a moderator asked me to do so)

Comment: According to http://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans, "One or two bad posts will not cause you to to be blocked from using the site."  Perhaps you made some bad posts on a different StackExchange site?  (I see that you have nine StackExchange accounts.)

Comment: Also, @bharb is not a moderator.  Moderators have a diamond symbol after their name.

Comment: Than who banned me ? you?

Comment: @tony9099 No, I do not have the priviliges to do so. And even if I did have them, I would have not blocked you. I would suggest contacting a moderator

Comment: @bharb okay. Thanks a lot. I'll check with them.

Comment: @tony9099, I think you should read the link I provided in my comment above.  There you will read "Stack Exchange has automatic filters in place to ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past."  So the ban was done automatically by the system, not by any user or moderator.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche thanks for clearing that up. Most probably the banning system was wrote by a 4th grader. anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer this question only because I can see that you try to learn cryptography which I've never studied, so I am envying you. Please note that consulting Wikipedia is always a good start.

**Do not ask questions here that could have been looked up in Wikipedia.**

(1) $\{0,1\}^d$ is a sequence of length $d$ consisting of zeros and ones. For instance $$0111001 \in\{0,1\}^7.$$

(2) $B$ is a function assigning elements of $\{0,1\}^d$ to elements of of the same set,  $\{0,1\}^d$. For instance: $$0000111\in 
\{0,1\}^7$$ and perhaps $B$ is such that

$$B(0000111)=0011000 \in\{0,1\}^7$$

(3) Uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^d$ assigns equal probabilities ($\frac{1}{2^d}$) to the members of $\{0,1\}^d$. This is like, as if, all the sequences were in a hat and you would draw one without any considerations.

(4) Go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(cryptography)) to learn the detais.

(5) In the case of pairs of elements of  $\{0,1\}^d$ you can do a comparison by comparing the members of the vector one by one with the XOR operation. Go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis) to learn more.

Comment: indeed. Thanks a lot for your time to give me these answers. I really appreciate it.